# When trying to install OATS(oracle Application Test Suite) getting an error saying "OUI-10151: There was an error while loading library:oatsQueries"

Tags: oracle, forms, testing, automation

When trying to install OATS(oracle Application Test Suite) getting an error saying "OUI-10151: There was an error while loading library:oatsQueries. Could some one let us know what could be the reason ?
Please find the snapshot for error below

Answer (score 0):

are you install OATS on Linux? which Linux version are you working on?

if true,

OUI is an Oracle installation tool, the OUI used in OATS for install need some 32bit library which may not exist on your system.

try to install the following:

```
yum install glibc.i686 

yum install libXext.i686 

yum install libXtst-devel.i686 

yum install libXrender.i386 

yum install libgcc.i686
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for your quick reply. We are using Windows 64 bit machine. Is this applicable there as well ?